# Updating the FAQ for a StackExchange site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, moderation, site-faq

Will moderators be able to update the FAQ page for a given stackexchange site?

We have discussed many changes on meta.stats.stackexchange.com and would like to implement them as there is some lingering confusion over the site's scope and usage.

Comment: I second this request. Same problem on cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: Any followup on this question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature was implemented yesterday, so moderators are now able to edit the FAQ.

Comment: ok so now all we need is a moderator election ! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62625/when-will-temporary-moderators-be-selected-for-new-se-sites-in-beta

Comment: I'm now a moderator on cstheory, and I can see the edit link for the first question in the FAQ (what is this site about). But I don't seem to able to edit anything else. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Suresh, yes only the top bit is editable. The rest of the page is a boilerplate (see Jeff's comment at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294/too-many-clueless-esri-users/295#295)