# Can we have the description of Stack Exchange site somewhere in the home page?

Tags: feature-request

When you visit any Stack Exchange site, the home page of the site lists the questions and few other stuff too; however, there is nowhere you can look at, and know what the purpose of the site is. Does my question fits in SuperUser or ServerFault? Is it a Stack Overflow or Programmers question?

What I want to see is some "About" section (or page) where I can go to and see what this site is for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the FAQ, linked in every site's header:

[image: Screenshot of the FAQ link]

The first question in the FAQ is ["What kind of questions can I ask here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), and each site can [customize](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61996/updating-the-faq-for-a-stackexchange-site) it as necessary

Comment: How could I miss that? Thanks :)

Comment: @TheBlueSky It used to pop up a big orange bar about it when you first visited a site, but they [got rid of that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129118/why-was-the-welcome-banner-removed)

Comment: That freehand red circle looks awfully square.

Comment: … actually, the OP is looking for the actual "About" section, not the FAQ.

Comment: The question actually sounds more like a `[site-rec]` question.... `"Does my question fits in..."`

Comment: @slhck The about section is almost entirely generic; there's one site-specific sentence at the beginning, but it tends to not be very illuminating